# contribute users have error while accessing silvelright web part

Tags: web-part, silverlight

I also have the same problem.. when i open silverlight web part in fullcontrol user login, it works fine.. but.. contribute users login means getting error. as

my application is

treeview

- child 1
- child 2
- child 3

if i check child 1, then new treeview will be created dynamically..
it shows the first treeview.. but stucks after checking the child node of the treeview..

```
Message: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem.GetFieldValue(String fieldName)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem.get_Item(String fieldName)
   at AuditNewTv.MainPage.chkbox_Checked(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton.OnChecked(RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton.OnIsCheckedPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.RaisePropertyChangeNotifications(DependencyProperty dp, Object oldValue, Object newValue)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, ValueOperation operation)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, Boolean allowReadOnlySet)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton.OnToggle()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(Control ctrl, EventArgs e)
   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
```

Any suggestions please..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Do the users actual have the permissions to see whatever it is that generates the treeview? Its hard to say without seeing your code, but if you are trying to pull a value that the query was not able to retrieve, it could give that error.